# Why do these calculators give different angles? ($244^\circ$ vs $-116^\circ$)

Tags: trigonometry

Why do these calculators give different angles? How do I fix it?

[image: a Casio calculator showing an angle of approximately $244 degrees, and a TI calculator showing an angle of approximately -116 degrees]

Comment: The angles are coterminal.

Comment: Both angles are to be understood as one and the same, One angle is anti-clockwise and another clockwise having same terminating radius vector in the third quadrant. No need to fix it,

Answer (score 1):

Note that $244.28^\circ \equiv -155.72^\circ$.

The angles are coterminal, meaning that $244.28^\circ$ and $-155.72^\circ$ are two different ways to express the same angle.

Answer (score 1):

Many "different" angles give the same results for most things: $244°$ works out, for most things, the same as $-116°$ and $604°$ and $-476°$ and many other angles: notice how all the trigonometric functions come out the same for all of those angles.  We say all of these angles are *equivalent*, and that they are all in the same *equivalence class*.  In the particular case of angles, two angles in the same equivalence class are called *co-terminal*.

Often, when talking about a particular equivalence class, we will select a representative from that class to use and do calculations on.  The important part of this is that it must be **selected**: there isn't generally one always-obviously-right answer!  These two calculators have selected their representatives for this equivalence class in two different ways: the Casio has chosen the one that matches $0°\le \theta < 360°$, and the TI has chosen the one that matches $-180° < \theta \le 180°$.  To "fix" it, if necessary, you can add or subtract $360°$ to representatives that fall outside your preferred range.